# How to bind variables to a jQuery getJSON call?

Tags: jquery, getjson

I need to access an outer, local variable from a jQuery JSON call without sending that variable to the server (therefore not using the data parameter):

```
for (var prop in channels) {
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(json) {
        channels[prop].value = ...;
    });
}
```

Unfortunately the `prop` vairable changes as the outer loop continues.

Is it possible to bind variables to the getJSON call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found the answer based on [jQuery's proxy function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
for (var prop in channels) { 
    $.getJSON(url).done(
        $.proxy(function(json) { 
            channels[this._prop].value = ...; 
        }, {_prop: prop}
    ); 
}
```

Essentially, `$.proxy()` creates a wrapper function that takes the additional `context` parameter and ensure that it is passed as `this` to the wrapped function.

Comment: Alternatively, it should also be possible to wrap the $.getJSON call in it's own function which would also maintain the function's parameters.

Comment: Finally found a answer, thanks! IE8 was giving me "object doesnt support property or method", took me a full day until this solution! Thanks!

Comment: I think that the wrapping the ajax function to create a closure will only use last value of the outer function not the value when it was called, but thanks  for the proxy pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Usage with js :bind:

```
for (var prop in channels) {
    $.getJSON(url).done(function(json) {
        channels[this].value = ...;
    }.bind(prop));
}
```

Usage with $.ajax context:

```
for (var prop in channels) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        dataType: 'json', 
        context: param, 
        success: function(data) {
            channels[this].value = ...;}
        })
}
```